# Laravel: Auth guard [sanctum] is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to implement auth in Laravel via [Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum). I did all steps from documentation. [Generation of Token](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#issuing-api-tokens) works fine but when I try to use `auth:sanctum` middleware it returns the error `Auth guard [sanctum] is not defined.`

Here are my files: 
**/routes/api.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard;


Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/dashboard/get_current_client/', [Dashboard::class, 'get_current_client']);

Route::get('/dashboard/client_data/', [Dashboard::class, 'client_data']);
```

**/config/auth.php**

```
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Client::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],


    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

**/app/Models/Client.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;



class Client extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'client';
    protected $primaryKey = 'client_id';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

**/app/Http/Controllers/Dashboard.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Client;



class Dashboard extends Controller
{
    public function client_data () {
        $user = Client::where('client_id', 1)->first();
        return $user->client_id;
    }

    public function get_current_client(Request $request) {
        var_dump($request->user());
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add Sanctum's middleware to your `api` middleware group within your application's `app/Http/Kernel.php` file as it is described in the docs?

Comment: do you mean adding this line?     \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
As far as I can see in docs it is needed only in case of using it for the own SPA. I'm planning to use it for the public.  So do not have a need for this. But just now added it to the experement. and it still didn't work out.

Comment: Ah yes, I meant this. That is strange. From what you described and did everything seems to be ok.

Comment: yea its acting like the Sanctum service provider never registered anything ... https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/blob/2.x/src/SanctumServiceProvider.php#L23

Comment: but why it could be so? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. For some reason cache in /bootstrap/cache has not updated. After manual removing it, everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

to fix it add the below code to file "**/bootstrap/cache/packages.php**"

```
'laravel/sanctum' => array (
'providers' => 
array (
  0 => 'Laravel\\Sanctum\\SanctumServiceProvider',
), ),
```